# Correct form of sum expression

Tags: notation, sequences-and-series

I want to create equation that represents following piece of code (it is much more complicated I simplify it for clearance)

int v = 23;
sum = 0;
for (int i = v; i > 0; i= i - 2)
{
sum = sum + i;
}

I want to write it like

$\sum^{i=i-2;i>0}_{i=v}$i

but I have feeling that it might not be the proper way.

Comment: What is the purpose of creating the equation? The code is probably as good as it gets, in general.

Comment: I need to put in an math article and it must be in a form of equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a finite sum, the order isn't important, and I don't think I have seen a sum where the order was specified as in a **for** loop.

You can write multiple conditions which have to be satisfied below the $\sum$. For example,

$$\sum_{\substack{p ~\text{prime} \\ p \equiv 1 \pmod 4}} \frac{1}{p^2}.$$

Your sum might be written as

$$\sum_{\substack{0\lt i \le v \\ v-i ~ \text{is even}}} i.$$